# How to transfer files securely P2P over internet?

Tags: security, encryption

Is there any way to exchange binary files over secure encrypted channel from one Android device to another, avoiding any public cloud services or 3rd party server?

Comment: I am sure you could use a intetnal FTP with a NAT or even XMPP chat?

Comment: Doesn't look like FTP is secure way to transfer file, even though somehow possible to overcome NAT issues.

Comment: What about rsync over ssh?

Comment: Looks too complex. I was thinking there is some way not for geeks.